# How to store multilayer objects in react redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, redux

I am trying to add multiple objects into `desire`'s object and store all of the desires that are collected inside this object. I am trying to set the key to the the date that it was set on, thus having an individual key for each record.

However all that is happening I end up with having an `desire` object in the state, which gets overwritten each time of writing and also `sex` and `masturbation` are removed with each update.

I know I should be able to get this, but its late and I'm stuck :D

**Reducer**

```
import Moment from 'moment';
import {
  SET_DESIRE_DATA,
  SET_MASTURBATION_DATA,
  SET_SEX_DATA
} from '../actions/dataAction';

const initialState = {
  'desire': {},
    'masturbation': {},
    'sex': {}
};

function desire (state = initialState, action) {
    //var action
    //{
    //    desire: 3, 
    //    date: Wed Jun 07 2017 23:45:41 GMT+0100 (BST)
    //}
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_DESIRE_DATA:
            //Date returned 07_06_2017
            //Moment(action.data.date).format('D-MM-YYYY')
            return {
                ...state.desire,
                desire: action.data
            }
        case SET_MASTURBATION_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                masturbation: action.data
            }
        case SET_SEX_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                sex: action.data
            }
    }
    return state
}

export default desire;
```

**Updated Store.desire**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function desire (state = initialState, action) {
    //var action
    //{
    //    desire: 3, 
    //    date: Wed Jun 07 2017 23:45:41 GMT+0100 (BST)
    //}
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_DESIRE_DATA:
            //Date returned 07_06_2017
            const key = Moment(action.data.date).format('D-MM-YYYY')
            const desire = Object.assign({}, state.desire);
            desire[key] = action.data
            return {
                ...state.desire,
                desire,
            }
        case SET_MASTURBATION_DATA:
          //similar code here
    }
    return state
}

export default desire;
```

Comment: Ah, in the morning things are much more clear :D Nice one